# Batch Scripts Will not run on some Windows 7 systems

Tags: batch-file

**Any ideas why bat files don't run in some cases?**

I have written an interactive batch script (also run as an exe) works on THOUSANDS of systems,  HOWEVER, a small subset of systems will NOT launch the script. They open a black box window and then close the script without giving the user the bat menu.  I tried the bat file association registry reset which ensures that .bat file association is correct but that didn't help.

**What I have tried: bat registry fix (.reg file)**

(which didn't seem to help, the script starts but doesn't run)

(I also tested a VERY basic script that printed Hello world which also didn't work)

Comment: Maybe is something about UAC or ACL...

Comment: Try calling it from the command line and post the output here...

Comment: Thanks. I solved that issue with my script by adding a UAC check BUT It seems that even a very basic script fails like "hello world".

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2550944/en-us

Comment: I had the user run her own script that printed hello world and it worked.  Interestingly the path for notepad was broken, I had to tell her to use the whole path.

Comment: Open a cmd prompt and type the batchfile name.  You'll see any error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your help.  What I found out was:

(1) Reset the command prompt:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/0a74090e-53ce-4642-8dad-0523bfd6c8a2/cant-run-bat-batch-files?forum=w7itproui
(which did not work for me)

(2) In a command prompt I had the users type 'set path' which showed that they were missing /windows/system32/ for one user. So far I had one user put it in and it fixed it. One other user had %systemroot%/system32 which I will have them try adding the path the other way to see if it fixes it. Next I will see if I can just add that to the script.